# How Update Latest record added record

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[masterTable]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedOn] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [State] [nchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
    
INSERT INTO [dbo].[masterTable] ([CID], [PID], [Description], [CreatedOn], [state])
VALUES (190, 186, 'FC1', GETUTCDATE())
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[masterTable] ([CID], [PID], [Description], [CreatedOn], [state])
VALUES (190, 186, 'FC2', GETUTCDATE())
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[masterTable] ([CID], [PID], [Description], [CreatedOn], [state])
VALUES (190, 186, 'FC3', GETUTCDATE())
GO
```

I have a table with 3 records I am trying to update the latest created on record with the state 'Latest data' and other old created on should update state with 'old data' I tried this but for old created on data not working. check the below query.

Explanation: we currently have a total of three records FC1,FC2 and FC3.

FC3 row is latest record based on createdon date column so, for this row state column should update with 'latest data' and other two records (FC1, FC2) are old records based on createdon date, so compare to FC3 row these two record is old data based on createdon date so state column should update with 'old data'.

```
WITH latestFC AS 
(
    SELECT TOP 1.*
    FROM [dbo].[masterTable]
    WHERE PID = 186
      AND CID = 190
    ORDER BY CreatedOn DESC
)
UPDATE latestFC
SET STATE = 'Latest Data'
```

Need help to handle both cases.

Comment: You only provided on row of data with your INSERT statement, can you provide more sample data and what you expect the result to be?

Comment: I have updated the details please check, if any more clarification is required let me know

Comment: Your `INSERT` statements list **five** columns that you want to insert into - but then your `VALUES` collection only provides **four** values.....

Answer (score 3):

First, you can `INSERT` multiple values into your table at once like this:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[masterTable]
           ([CID]
           ,[PID]
           ,[Description]
           ,[CreatedOn]
           )
     VALUES
           (190
           ,186
           ,'FC1'
           ,GETUTCDATE()),
           (190
           ,186
           ,'FC2'
           ,DATEADD(d, +1, GETUTCDATE())),
            (190
            ,186
            ,'FC3'
           ,DATEADD(d, +2, GETUTCDATE()))
```

**Note** that I've added some days to the *FC2 & FC3* rows in order to get the result that you wanted for the `UPDATE` statement.

Second, you don't need a `CTE` like you attempted above to do this simple `UPDATE`. You can use a `CASE` statement inside the `WHERE` clause after you get the `MAX` CreatedOn date:

```
UPDATE masterTable SET State = 
CASE WHEN CreatedOn = (SELECT MAX(CreatedOn) FROM masterTable)
THEN 'Latest data'
ELSE 'Old data'
END
```

Third, some design and syntax issues: your `[State]` column is set to `[nchar](10)`, I would increase this to `[nchar](15)` at a minimum because entering the string *'Latest data'* will result in the value getting truncated to *'Latest dat'* since its **11** characters long and your column only holds **10** characters. Also, your `INSERT` statement has too many columns and not enough values. Either remove `[state]` from the `INSERT` or add a value for the `[state]` column.

Last but not least, here's a [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5921776d3b2d9c6ac7938f36a6584917) for your reference.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73608665/12296803 please look into it